# Simple Powershell script to find file and email if found

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm attempting to write simple script to run from a Windows 2008 R2 server.  The purpose of the script is to have it run on a schedule.  If it finds the file, it emails me the path.  If it doesn't find the file, it does nothing.

If I use the script below from my workstation (Windows 7 64 bit SP1, running Powershell 4.0) it works fine.  However, if I run the same script from my server (same version of Powershell) by simply changing the i: to s: it wont run.  If I input the UNC path \san\fileshare, instead of the drive letter, it will run however, if it does not find the file, it still emails a blank report file.  I've tried several iterations of this script and I come to the same conclusion.

Little help, please....

```
$ChkFile = "i:\*.*"

$FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile -Include "TestFile.TXT"

If ($FileExists -eq $True)
{

    $a = "TestFile.TXT"

    Get-ChildItem -Path i:\*.* -Filter $a -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File c:\utils\TestFile.TXT_I_Drive.txt

    $today = Get-Date -Format D

    Send-MailMessage -From "me <myemail@ExchangeServer.com>" -To "me <myemail@ExchangeServer.com>" -SmtpServer ExchangeServer.domain.com -Body "Please see attached report TestFile_I_Drive.txt"  -Subject "Hidden file found $today" -Attachments c:\utils\TestFile_I_Drive.txt

}
Else 
{
   Exit
}
```

Comment: I would get rid of the errorAction silentlycontinue and see what if any errors you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your response Andy. 

When I remove the errorAction and silentlyconinute flags, the response reveals a few directories the script could not access due to known permissions.  

Specifically I receive a Get-ChildItem :  Access to the path 'S:\directory' is denied.

Comment: If you are running this as a scheduled task it might not have access to the mapped drive you are using. `Get-ChildItem` does support UNC paths so just use the real path instead. Also this is a typo in script `Out-Filee`

Comment: True, about the scheduled task.  However, the script still sends a blank text file, when I am logged in.

Comment: The scheduled task doesn't care if you're logged in or not -- it does not execute as you. Why is using a UNC path a problem? As long as the scheduler's account has access to the share, everything will work fine :) When you map a drive, it is only available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't doing a test-path on the file itself rather then as an include?  Try changing the code to just read as below and let me know how you go:

```
$CheckFile = \\UNC\Testfile.txt;
If(Test-path $CheckFile){..
```